# Nvidia GTX 460M laggy display

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, video

The best way to describe what is happening with words is to think of a video where if I grabbed my nautilus window and moved it from one side of the screen to the other.  Now think of that video and I removed lots of frames in the processes so the window basically starts where I grabbed in and everything in between is lost.

I have a stock install with the Nvidia drivers that got installed during the graphical installer.  I had the issue so then I installed the "Post-Release-Updates" and the problem still isn't fixed.

Lovin unity, but I haven't been able to use it since 10.xx

Any ideas?

THIS IS THE LOG AFTER INSTALLING FROM NVIDIA SITE
New xorg.log

http://pastebin.com/L2jrJCey

Comment: Try installing the nvidia drivers from nvidia homepage. This works fine for me.However, each time you change kernel version you have to reinstall it again :(

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Where you using the same Video card?  Or did you just have the same issue.

Comment: Neither nor, I just never had problems with the nvidia driver installed this way.I have a GTS250.However, they all use the same driver and GTX460M should work as it is not a rarely used graphics adapter.

Comment: I installed the newest version using the x-swat ppa.  That is version 290.* and it still lags.  Any optimization advice?

Comment: I opened a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/903395

Comment: Is it also laggy in gnome classic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Comment: I'm using Unity at the moment haven't tried Gnome classic.  Here is my updated xorg.log after uninstalling/purging old nvidia stuff and reinstalling drivers directly from Nvidia's site.

Comment: Lekensteyn - It says my card has optimus, but running a command I get 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF106 [GeForce GTX 460M] (rev a1)

This shows only one card which means I don't have an intel/nvidia conflict correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the problem is my mouse oddly enough.

I have an **ASUS Republic of Gamers** mouse which is probably made by Logitech or uses the same guts.  Supposedly these mouses are the issue.  Not sure on the actual fix, but I unplugged the sucker and restarted and all is well, but now I have no mouse besides this track pad...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, only a misconfiguration:

```
[ 11.389] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 11.389] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
```

From those two entries you can see that the NVidia driver is not loaded, instead the vesa driver is loaded. You wont have performance that way, especially not with unity.Can you have a look whether /etc/X11/xorg.conf exists and search for a section "Device" and in this section for the entry "Driver" . There you will find:

```
Driver "nv"
```

Replace this by:

```
Driver "nvidia"
```

And still the suggestion: Use the driver directly from Nvidia!!!!!!!!! The driver installation also takes care for setting up your X-Server correctly which seems to be not correct in your case.

Comment: I installed the nvidia drivers from the site.  Still same problem unfortunately.  Here is my xorg.log please see if there is any more errors I need to fix.  http://pastebin.com/L2jrJCey

Comment: Do you have the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file? If yes, please also add this file. The xorg.log I also had, the two lines are from this file, which I found in your bug report (which I also marked as invalid, as the two lines show a misconfiguration of your system). More information is necessary to help you out there.

Comment: Here is a link to the xorg.conf file http://pastebin.com/eb5dA6W0

Comment: Ah its a new log file now, sorry :-D - now the driver seems to load correctly. Next step is to check OpenGL support. What does 'glxinfo | grep rendering' output? Does glxgears work?

Comment: Here is that output : direct rendering: Yes
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering,

Comment: Then I suggest reading the information in this bug report, try the suggestions there and maybe also the information in the bug reports mentioned in this report. It might be the same problem which you face. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/861061 - especially the syncing parameters mentioned there could be a possible cause. Did glxgears run "laggy" or normal?

Comment: I think it relates specifically to Unity.  glxgears ran with no problems and I can run games under Ubuntu no issues.  Here is the output from running it for awhile

46420 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9283.950 FPS
48388 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9677.535 FPS
48164 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9631.639 FPS
47113 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9421.119 FPS
48363 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9672.534 FPS
47844 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9568.724 FPS
49048 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9809.471 FPS
49322 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9864.326 FPS
45250 frames in 5.0 seconds = 9049.979 FPS

Comment: Well finally you have both - first incorrect graphics driver (solved now) and something wrong with unity.However, from here on I am sorry to say that I cannot help you anymore as I still use gnome classic and will soon switch to LXDE desktop. I do not like Unity. But please first read the mentioned bug report and the related ones before considering reopening your initial bug report. Also you may try googeling for unity, lagg, issue, synchronisation, bug. Especially this might help: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Ubuntu_11.04_choppy_or_slow

Comment: Well appreciate your help.  Unity to me is everything that Gnome Classic is with extra coolness.  The idea of putting the menu in one location for all apps saves screen space.  Alt-Tab replaces a window or task bar for me.  I am reluctant for change as well.. it took me awhile to accept Gnome 3 and Unity.

Comment: If you find a solution finally, please also answer your question ;-) This helps others with your problem!

Comment: Well Michael K.  I think the bugs you showed me exist, but I think they are unrelated or the fixes they gave do nothing for this issue.